# Is it considered unsafe if users can see your php code?

Tags: php

As we all know it is possible to see the html, css and javascript code of any page on internet.(viewing the source code)

I tried to view the php code of websites and discovered that that's not possible.

Is it considered dangerous/unsafe (for the websites security) to allow users to view the php codes?

or is it just that php is server-side scripting language?

Comment: Stop downvoting just because you think he's a n00b.

Comment: didn't expect so many down votes, anyways i accept that i am a noob n it has only been 2 hrs since i started learning php.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first step to bypassing any system or security, is knowledge of how it is designed or built. **YES**, if a malicious user can view your PHP source code, they **CAN** find ways to exploit it. If you have your server configured properly, then no outside (Web) user will be able to SEE the source, though.